# Drupal: $form['#redirect'] = FALSE; doesn't work

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I've tried to change the redirection when I submit my edit-node form, by addming the following line to my template.php file, in my theme

```
$form['#redirect'] = FALSE;
```

I'm sure the template.php file works well because I have other lines in which I change, for example, the weights of some elements. But the redirection doesn't work.

I've also tried $form['#redirect'] = 'anotherPage'; without success.

What am I doing wrong ? I'm following the Drupal APIs, about forms:
http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#redirect

thanks

Comment: Do you want to be kept at the node editing form?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

IIRC, the `$form['#redirect']` entry will only be effective if no other redirection is set later on in the form processing. If you [take a look at `node_form_submit()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/node_form_submit/6), you can see that it sets its own redirection via `$form_state['redirect'] = 'node/'. $node->nid;`, thus overriding the redirection you defined in the form definition earlier on.

You can work around this by [adding your own submit handler callback](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#submit-prop) to the `$form['#submit']` array (needs to be placed *after* the default one). Within that callback, you can change the `$form_state['redirect']` to your desired path.

NOTE: If the `$form['#submit']` array does not yet contain the default entry during `hook_form_alter()`, you might need to add another indirection by [adding a callback to `$form['#after_build']`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#after_build) - within that callback, you have a final chance to manipulate the form array before it gets rendered. (Well, almost final - there is still [`$form['#pre_render']`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6#pre_render) later on ;)

Comment: Much clearer than my answer. Nice tip about $form['#after_build'] saves messing around with module weights.

Comment: @Jermey French: Yup, $form['#after_build'] can be quite handy. However, if two forms use it, you still end up messing around with module weights :/ (Unless you go one higher and start using '#pre_render' - took me two hours once to grok how CCK managed to completely ignore/override my node field order adjustments ;)

Comment: Not only did you answer this u up'd the ante, by providing a REALLY complete answer. Well done, HO. :)

Answer (score 2):

You should create a module and use [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_form_alter) to alter the form before it is displayed. Generally you shouldn't manipulate data and behaviour in the theming layer.

You may be able to use [drupal_rebuild_form()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_rebuild_form/6), in the .tpl file to avoid this, but I don't know what other consequences this will have.

Comment: ok 1) where should I implement hook_form_alter() function ?  2) what should be its name node_form_alter() ? (should I include it in back-end theme folder ?)

Comment: Modules are not themes and have different naming conventions. You will need to have a look at some module development how tos.